# How do I form the correct regular expression to capture everything before parentheses?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

current I have a set strings that are of the format

```
customName(path/to/the/relevant/directory|file.ext#FileRefrence_12345)
```

From this I could like to extract customName, the characters before the first parentheses, using sed.

My best guesses so far are:

```
echo $s | sed 's/([^(])+\(.*\)/\1/g'
echo $s | sed 's/([^\(])+\(.*\)/\1/g'
```

However, using these I get the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: Unmatched ( or \(
```

So how do I form the correct regular expression? and why is it relevant that I do not have a matched \( is it is just an escaped character for my expression, not a character used for formatting?

Comment: Careful, in `sed`, `(` is a literal parenthesis, and `\(` starts a capturing group, not vice versa.

Comment: Ah! Wonderful! Thanks @TimPietzcker , that clears up a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could substitute everything after the opening parenthesis, like this (note that parentheses by default do not need to be escaped in `sed`)

```
echo 'customName(path/to/the/relevant/directory|file.ext#FileRefrence_12345)' |
sed -e 's/(.*//'
```

Comment: I may have a misunderstand of how part of sed works. Shouldn't parens need escaping because they signal grouping? such as in the command 's/(need)le/\1/g' which I think replaces "needle" with "need"

Comment: @Matt, see [sed regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) . Grouping is done using `\(group\)`

Answer (score 2):

**grep**

```
kent$  echo "customName(blah)"|grep -o '^[^(]*'
customName
```

**sed**

```
kent$  echo "customName(blah)"|sed 's/(.*//'   
customName
```

note I changed the stuff between the brackets.

Comment: +1 for the `grep` one, did not thing on that. Btw, so good to see you here again.

Answer (score 1):

Different options:

```
$ echo $s | sed 's/(.*//'            #sed (everything before "(")
customName
$ echo $s | cut -d"(" -f1            #cut (delimiter is "(", print 1st block)
customName
$ echo $s | awk -F"(" '{print $1}'   #awk (field separator is "(", print 1st)
customName
$ echo ${s%(*}                       #bash command substitution
customName
```